# No Device Available

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Flutter in VS code and it is not showing me any device to run my flutter on.

[image]

In my cmd it is showing me devices to run it on like windows but in vs code it's showing nothing.
Kindly explain me the steps of procedures to follow to run my flutter code on windows or chrome.

Answer (score 0):

When you press F5. It should sgow the list of devices.
You said that in cmd it show devices.
If it don't work make sure that you have created a device.
If not you can create one from android studion in device manager.
Or i think there is a plugin in vs for a virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

You can install android studio and then can use the AVD emulator. You can follow [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio?gclid=Cj0KCQjwoK2mBhDzARIsADGbjeovzaVvRIhiO0J7Do1aZ8g8mpH1lfqtFOMA4_1icXWEgGAH0n6yT7EaArOREALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) to install Android Studio and set up device.